# How to get watchman build from RC releases?

Tags: system-installation, compiling

When I run: `$ ./autogen.sh && ./configure && make`
It returns: `your system lacks libtoolize`

Steps I took:

- Clone Watchman

  ```
  $ git clone https:gitbub.com/facebook/watchman.git
  $ cd watchman/
  ```
- Checkout the newest version.

  ```
  $ git checkout v4.9.0
  ```
- Install Watchman

  ```
  $ sudo apt-get install -y autoconf automake build-essential python-dev
  ```
- Build

  ```
  $ ./autogen.sh && ./configure && make
  ```

How to fix: `your system lacks libtoolize`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that there is a tool needed for running:

```
$ ./autogen.sh && ./configure && make
```

We need `libtool` for that job. To install `libtool`:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install libtool
```

If make throws warnings: `$ ./configure --enable-lenient` to not have warnings yield a compilation error.